# Faster way in generating default dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a faster way in generating a dictionary with a certain default value?  I basically want an equavalent of

```
arrays = [True] * (n+1)
```

but for dictionary.  I currently have:

```
dicts = dict([(i,True) for i in range(0,n+1)])
```

The problem is with n = 1000000, the times I am getting with this implementation is 0.016s for the array and 0.318 for the dicts.  Is there a faster way to do this for the dictionary?

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(range(n + 1), True)`

Comment: That takes 0.177 seconds for 1 million keys. You can't get much faster, as hashing and slotting 1 million keys into a hash table takes more time than building an array of 1 million references.

Comment: Ok thanks, this works.  Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

Yup. [`dict.fromkeys` is designed for this exact use case](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys). Your example `dicts` could be made directly with:

```
dicts = dict.fromkeys(range(n + 1), True)
```

Slightly slower, but more flexible, are `dict` comprehensions (2.7/3.1+):

```
dicts = {i: True for i in range(n + 1)}
```

That will be a little slower in 3.x, and slower than that in 2.x (because `True` is a keyword in 3.x and doesn't invoke LEGB lookup, but it's only a normal built-in name in 2.x and therefore has to perform multiple `dict` lookups under the hood on each use, just in case it's been reassigned). `dict.fromkeys` will be just as fast in either case, because `True` is only looked up once.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanations